# Java ME SDK 3 fails to start

Tags: java-me, sdk

I downloaded & installed the latest JDK & Java ME SDK. Both seemed to install fine.

However, when I try to run the SDK, when the progress bar at the splash screen gets to "starting modules..." it hangs for a while, and then starts to pop exceptions of the form:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:525)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:475)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:372)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:186)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:22)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:128)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:595)
Caused: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:97)
Caused: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect]
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:101)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:185)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1886)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1856)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:257)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:338)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:248)
    at com.sun.jme.toolkit.remoting.client.rmiimpl.ObjectServerConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jme.toolkit.remoting.client.rmiimpl.ObjectServerConnectionImpl.start(Unknown Source)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jme.toolkit.bootstrap.Batch.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jme.toolkit.bootstrap.Batch.tryInvoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jme.toolkit.bootstrap.Batch.startObjects(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.modules.javame.common.container.Module.start(Module.java:21)
    at org.netbeans.modules.javame.common.container.ContainerSupport.startModule(ContainerSupport.java:67)
    at org.netbeans.modules.javame.common.container.devicemanager.DevicemanagerHelper.getDeviceManagerConnection(DevicemanagerHelper.java:41)
    at org.netbeans.modules.javame.common.container.devicemanager.DevicemanagerHelper.ensureConnected(DevicemanagerHelper.java:48)
    at org.netbeans.modules.javame.common.container.devicemanager.DevicemanagerHelper.getDeviceManager(DevicemanagerHelper.java:84)
    at org.netbeans.modules.javame.platform.jme_sdk.autoinstaller.AutoInstaller.ensureDMStarted(AutoInstaller.java:292)
    at org.netbeans.modules.javame.platform.jme_sdk.autoinstaller.AutoInstaller.restored(AutoInstaller.java:63)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.NbInstaller.loadCode(NbInstaller.java:421)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.NbInstaller.load(NbInstaller.java:342)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:906)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.installNew(ModuleList.java:428)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.trigger(ModuleList.java:364)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleSystem.restore(ModuleSystem.java:276)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:165)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:312)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(TopThreadGroup.java:110)
[catch] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Google reveals that I'm not the only one experiencing this problem, hoewever I wasn't able to find any solution.

Any one has any idea about this?

Answer (score 6):

I'm on Win64 Professional.  I had both a 32-bit and 64-bit JDK and found I had to use the 32-bit JDK or I got the error you mention.

I found that a file named "java" in installDir\bin and installDir\toolbar\bin had the path to the JDK, so I updated both to the 32-bit JDK and then it worked.  I hope that helps either you or others.

(Thanks to http://java.lillegutt.com/?p=3)

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem when I launched the SDK after install. Unfortunately none of the suggestions were helpful.

After a lot of experiments the following worked:

There is a program running "Java ME SDK 3.0 Device Manager" which is visible in the Tray. Exit this program and then launch the SDK. The Device Manager will be launched by the SDK and the IDE was open finally!